# Scroll bar like Google is using

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

With the most latest updates Google has been rolling out, the sites have all been getting custom JS scroll bars (at least in Chrome).

What I like most about it is that its simple and works perfectly. Until now a lot of the JS scrollers that I have seen don't function that well - i.e. if you scroll really fast or scroll and move your mouse around they don't function that well.

Hence I'm just wondering if anyone know of any scroller out there that is simple/small (code foot print is small) and functions well (as mentioned about).

I have thought about using jQueryUI's scroll as a base, but for my needs I can't take on jQueryUI for this one feature.

Comment: Try reversing Google's scrollbar? :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're done by styling [`::-webkit-scrollbar`](http://www.webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/) psudo-elements with CSS, not JS.

Comment: Didn't even think that it would be done like that, hence why I didn't look. Makes more sense now, how it works so well and only in Webkit.

Comment: IE also has its own scrollbar CSS attributes, such as `scrollbar-face-color` and `scrollbar-shadow-color`

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the [lion bars jquery scroller](http://charuru.github.io/lionbars/), and I think it meets all the specifications you mentioned, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://gist.github.com/fanzeyi/3995618

Works fine for me.