# Change Scroll Website Like Google

Tags: javascript, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scroll bar like Google is using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971069/scroll-bar-like-google-is-using)

Default scroll in website is so simple look, lately I visit blogger, and scroll in blogger is not user scroll like default website. They change it to an image (maybe), so I want to ask everyone. "Can I Change The Scroll of my website to become like Google ?"

Maybe my english is not good, but it because I am Indonesian :D

Answer (score 1):

This can be done through [CSS and Webkit](http://www.webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/) or with [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/). Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742143/how-are-scrollbars-in-new-google-docs-ui-styled-esp-the-arrow-buttons) SO question. Note, if you use Webkit, it'll only render in Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 1):

I believe they've only changed the scroll bar in certain browsers like Chrome. Here's how to do it: http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/